# Is translation operator norm-preserving on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and consider the translation operator $T_h: L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ given by $T_h(f) = f(x-h)$ for some $h \in \mathbb{R}$. I was wondering if it was true that $\|T_h f\|_\infty = \|f\|_\infty$. At first this seems true of course right? I mean you look at a function and look at the essential supremum, then slide it wherever you want and this should not change the essential supremum. So I do believe this is true, but I have seen some posts about it not being a continuous operator. Usually they take the indicator of $[0,1]$ as a counterexample. Are these two things related or are they distinct from each other?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding here. The identity $\lVert T_h f\rVert_\infty = \lVert f\rVert_\infty$ is of course true for all $h\in\mathbb R$. Since $T_h$ is a linear operator, this implies that the map
$$
f\in L^\infty \mapsto T_h f \in L^\infty
$$
is continuous. Notice that here $h$ is just a fixed number.

On the other hand, if you fix $f\in L^\infty$ and consider the map
$$
h\in\mathbb R \mapsto T_h f\in L^\infty, $$
then this one is not necessarily continuous; for example, it is not if $f=\mathbf 1_{[0, 1]}$, for in this case
$$
\lVert T_\epsilon f- T_0 f\rVert_\infty=1, \quad \forall \epsilon\ne 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.